# Deployment on artifactory failed via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder

Comment: Utilize code blocks (search for Markdown inline code blocks). Also, provide more details.

Comment: I recommend upgrading all the installed plugins. The issue looks like one of the plugins uses an old version of the Apache HTTP client library.